# Should position() as used here work to retrieve node with same position in two subsets of tags in xslt 2.0?

Tags: xml, qt, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a list of nodes defined in two subsets like this:

```
<top>
  <left>
    <name>One</value>
    <name>Two</value>
    <name>Three</value>
    <name>Four</value>
  </left>
  <right>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>3</value>
    <value>4</value>
  </right>
</top>
```

I want to transform those with the name on the left and the value on the right:

```
<division>
   <name>One</name><value>1</value>
</division>
<division>
   <name>Two</name><value>2</value>
</division>
<division>
   <name>Three</name><value>3</value>
</division>
<division>
   <name>Four</name><value>4</value>
</division>
```

What I came up with so far is the following. I loop through the names and try to pick the corresponding value using an index.

```
<xsl:for-each select="top/left/name/node()">
  <division>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/> <!-- this works just fine -->

    <!-- get position of <name> tag -->
    <xsl:variable name="index"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../../right/value/node[position() = $index]"/>
  </division>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If I replace `$index` by `1` in `node[position() == $index]`, then I get the correct value (but obviously it will always be `"1"`.) Similarly, I can set `$index` to `2`, `3`, or `4` and I get the correct value each time.

However, I have not been able to get the correct value with the `$index` variable as shown in the code above.

I think this is a bug in the `QtXmlPatterns` implementation, but would like to make sure this is how you would do it too? Maybe there is another way, which would allow me to avoid the Qt bug?

Just in case, I tried to use the following:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
```

by itself just before or after the `<xsl:variable ...` definition and it shows me 1, 2, 3 and 4 just as I would expect. Yet, the:

```
 <xsl:copy-of select="../../right/value/node[position() = $index]"/>
```

only shows me the first value (i.e. it looks like `$index` is always set to the value `1` instead of the incrementing position as expected.)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try it this way:

```
<xsl:for-each select="top/left/name">
    <division>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
        <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../../right/value[$index]"/>
    </division>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Your attempt fails mainly because the text nodes are always first (and only) nodes within their parent `value` element.

---

Note that this assumes a well-formed XML:

```
<top>
  <left>
    <name>One</name>
    <name>Two</name>
    <name>Three</name>
    <name>Four</name>
  </left>
  <right>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>3</value>
    <value>4</value>
  </right>
</top>
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I would expect. On my end, I always get 1 in the `$index` variable. However, if I display the `position()` directly, as in `<xsl:copy-of select="position()"/>` it shows `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` as expected. So I'm really sure that the Qt implementation does it wrong.

Comment: Okay, I created a couple of files, and as I would expect with Qt, it fails. But at least this shows me that I'm not the one going crazy. It looks like the `position()` is calculated at the time the `$index` is calculated and that means it uses the `position()` of the `select="../../right/value[$index]"` as if you were writing `select="../../right/value[position()]"`, which is rather useless.